# XOR of two hexadecimal strings in python

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

I have two string values with char and hex equivalent. How do I XOR both the strings such that result should be in this format "\x00\x01\x... "

where:
**String1 and String2 are equal with there corresponding ASCII values**

```
String1 = "abcd"

String2 = "\x61\x62\x63\x64"

String3 = String1 ^ String2
```

**Input:**

```
String1 = "ABC"
String2 = "\x72\x61\x74"
```

**I'm using the below approach to find an XOR value**

```
hex(ord('A')) ^ '\x72' = ??
hex(ord('B')) ^ '\x61' = ??
hex(ord('C')) ^ '\x74' = ??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are thinking of is either:

```
String1 = "ABC"
String2 = "\x72\x61\x74"
result = "".join(chr(c1 ^ c2) for c1, c2 in zip(map(ord, String1), map(ord, String2)))
print(result)
# prints "3#7"
```

Or, if you want to print the hexadecimal representation, maybe:

```
String1 = "ABC"
String2 = "\x72\x61\x74"
result = "".join("\\x{:02x}".format(c1 ^ c2) for c1, c2 in zip(map(ord, String1), map(ord, String2)))
print(result)
# prints "\x33\x23\x37"
```